# Representation of Ito integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

If $W_t$ is Brownian motion, is it true that for any Ito integrable function $f$, 
$$\int_0^t f(u) dW_u = W_tf(t) - \int_0^t W_uf'(u)du$$?

I've seen this represntation used a couple of times without proof, and I was wondering  if it was true in general or if there are some specific properties $f$ must satisfy.

If true, how can it be proved? I've tried applying Ito's formula to the right hand side, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a result of the [Stochastic Leibniz Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation#Semimartingales), i.e., 
$$
{\rm d}\left(X_tY_t\right)=Y_t{\rm d}X_t+X_t{\rm d}Y_t+{\rm d}\left<X,Y\right>_t,
$$
where $\left<X,Y\right>$ denotes the co-variation of $X$ and $Y$.

Back to your question, simply put $X_t=f(t)$ and $Y_t=W_t$, and
$$
{\rm d}\left(f(t)W_t\right)=W_t{\rm d}f(t)+f(t){\rm d}W_t+{\rm d}\left<f,W\right>_t.
$$
Note that $f$ is deterministic, for which ${\rm d}f(t)=f'(t){\rm d}t$ and $\left<f,W\right>=0$. The above result reduces to
$$
{\rm d}\left(f(t)W_t\right)=f'(t)W_t{\rm d}t+f(t){\rm d}W_t.
$$
The integration of this last equation immediately leads to the formula you expect.

Comment: This is a form of integration by parts, no?

Comment: @SeanRoberson: Yes, you may regard it as a form of integration by parts--in stochastic calculus, by taking the co-variation term into consideration.